# How do you search for all the files that contain a particular string?

Tags: string, search, recursion

Let's say you're working on a big project with multiple files, directories, and subdirectories. In one of these directories/subdirectories/files, you've defined a method, but now you want to know exactly which files in your entire project have been calling your method. How do you do this?

Comment: in what language would is you project written?
c++, java, ..?

Comment: mostly java. but isn't there a way to do this using "grep" somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is by using your editor. For example emacs can do this if you create a tag index with etags.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html

The you just types M-. and type the name of the function you want to visit and emacs will take you there.

I don't know what system or which editor you are using but most editors has a simular function.

If you don't use emacs an other good way to keep track of functions, and get a lots of other good features, is to use a versions control system. Like git, it provides really fast search.

If you don't use a version control system you may want to look at a program that is designed just for searching. Like [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned grep so I'll throw this solution out there. A more robust solution would be to implement a version control system as Fibbe suggested.

`find . -exec grep 'method_name' {} \; -print 2> /dev/null`

The idea is, for each file that is found in the current directory and sub-directories, a grep for 'method_name' is executed on that file. The `2> /dev/null` is nice if you don't want to get warned about all of the directories and files you don't have access to.